# How can I use removeAllChildrenWithCleanup: w/o losing runAction:?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have an transformation sequence that works fine until I add in removeAllChildrenWithCleanup: at the end of the sequence.  What can I do to keep the transformation sequence and run removeAllChildrenWithCleanup: at the end?

Here's a snippet of the code in question:

```
// Note: spriteSheet is a CCSpriteBatchNode
CCArray *oldSprites = [spriteSheet descendants];
for (int j=0; j < (int)[oldSprites count]; j++) {
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[oldSprites objectAtIndex:j];
    if (sprite != nil) {
        id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.75
                                            position:ccp(0,0)];
        [sprite runAction:actionMove];
    }
}
[spriteSheet removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
```

Note: I've tried cleaning up the sprite by using a sequence of CCMoveTo then CCCallFuncND to clean up the sprite, but it doesn't work either.  I'm try to use removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:, because I know that removing a child from a CCSpriteBatchNode is very slow.

Comment: I don't understand. Of course if you remove all children then they will disappear from screen. The cleanup option determines whether they'll stop their actions as well. And just because something "could be" slow doesn't mean you shouldn't use it. It's a bit slower but you'll probably not be able to notice it.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : the problem is that the transformation sequence no longer occurs once I add in the line about removing the children.  I was expecting the transformation sequence to occur and then have the children removed.  But the actual result is that the children just get removed (and the transformation sequence doesn't occur).

Comment: Well then remove the children *after* the sequence ended, of course. Use a CCCallBlock/Func to do that at the end of the sequence. I think you thought that the actions would run to the end before the removeAll.. method is executed, but that is not the case. The actions are added, the removeAll.. function runs immediately afterwards. The actions don't have any chance of running and doing their job.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : I tried your suggestion of using CCCallBlock at the end of the sequence.  The result is an inconsistent behavior of either the transformation sequence not running still, or the sequence running, but the following sequence (which I didn't mention before) after the clean not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried CCCallBlock? Something like this:

```
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.75 position:ccp(0,0)];
id actionDelay = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; }];
id sequence = [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionDelay, nil];
[sprite runAction:sequence];
```

Comment: Thank you.  The CCCallBlock with removeFromParentAndCleanup worked perfectly.  (I tried CCCallBlock before, but I was using removeChild:cleanup:, which lead to inconsistent behavior.)